# Mapping against list of Scala tuples with default arguments

Tags: scala, mapping, tuples, default-value

This works when I'm trying to map a case class constructor against a list of tuples:

```
scala> case class MyClas(x:Int, y:String, z:String)
defined class MyClas

scala> Seq((1,"hey","you"), (2, "blue","shoe")) map Function.tupled(MyClas)
res1: Seq[MyClas] = List(MyClas(1,hey,you), MyClas(2,blue,shoe))
```

But when there is a default argument in the class constructor:

```
scala> case class MyClas(x:Int, y:String, z:String, zz:String="blue")
defined class MyClas

scala> Seq((1,"hey","you"), (2, "blue","shoe")) map Function.tupled(MyClas)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : MyClas.type
 required: (Int, String, String) => ?
              Seq((1,"hey","you"), (2, "blue","shoe")) map Function.tupled(MyClas)
```

The following works, but it feels like there should be an easier way:

```
scala> Seq((1,"hey","you"), (2, "blue","shoe")) map Function.tupled((x,y,z)=>MyClas(x,y,z))
res3: Seq[MyClas] = List(MyClas(1,hey,you,blue), MyClas(2,blue,shoe,blue))
```

Edit: Oh, I forgot to clarify that this is Scala 2.10.4, but according to @mohit's comment, this now works in Scala 2.11. Interesting.

Comment: works in scala 2.11.6, java 1.7.0_71.

Comment: `.map { case (x, y, z) => MyClas(x, y, z) }` is a little better, but I think it's the best you're going to get.

Comment: Another way to simplify your code a bit: `map Function.tupled(MyClas(_, _, _))`

Comment: @Kolmar, if you post your code as a solution I would accept it, as it is quite concise.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a companion object and define a tupled method for Tuple4 and Tuple3:

```
case class MyClas(x:Int, y:String, z:String, zz: String = "blue") {
}

object MyClas {
   def tupled(a: (Int, String, String)) = new MyClas(a._1, a._2, a._3)
   def tupled(a: (Int, String, String, String)) = new MyClas(a._1, a._2, a._3, a._4)
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
Seq((1, "hey", "you"), (2, "blue", "shoe")).map(MyClas.tupled)
Seq((1, "hey", "you", "blah"), (2, "blue", "shoe", "blah")).map(MyClas.tupled)
```

Comment: Thanks Roman, but I think this is a little more boilerplate than I was hoping for (more so than the anonymous function anyways).